# PTIJ: Which fodder should a child be fed?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The Talmud says ([Ketubot 50a](https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.50a.6?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> אמר ליה רב לרב שמואל בר שילת בציר מבר שית לא תקביל בר שית קביל וספי ליה כתורא
>
> Rav say to Rav Shmuel bar Sheilat, who taught children: With regard to a child less than six years old, do not accept him; if he is six years old, accept him and stuff him like an ox.

Must I follow local practices, or is it preferable to follow the majority--whether it be grass-fed or otherwise?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't get this question. "Which fodder"? Most children only have one fodder, and either him or the modder could feed them.

Comment: @MichoelR I'd certainly hope that's not the one the OP is asking about! That "children will eat their fodders" is a sad prediction in Yechezkel (5:10).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe common practise is to feed them anything and everything!

It famously says in [Devarim 22:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.22.1?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=he&aliyot=0):

> לֹֽא־תִרְאֶה֩ אֶת־שׁ֨וֹר אָחִ֜יךָ א֤וֹ אֶת־שֵׂיוֹ֙ נִדָּחִ֔ים וְהִתְעַלַּמְתָּ֖ מֵהֶ֑ם הָשֵׁ֥ב תְּשִׁיבֵ֖ם לְאָחִֽיךָ׃

This is to be translated as follows:

> If you see your fellow’s ox (i.e. their child)...do not ignore it; you must take it back (לְאָחִֽיךָ) to your fire-pot brazier*.

Thus there is a very clear Torah injunction to feed not just your own children with any food, but even if you see a wandering child of your friend you must immediately take him with you and cook him some food.

*As seen for example in [Yirmiyahu 36:23](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.36.23?ven=Tanakh:_The_Holy_Scriptures,_published_by_JPS&lang=bi)